# Installing XSP on CentOS

Tags: centos, make, mono

Trying to install xsp-2.10.2. Worked fine in the past, now getting this error.

```
Making install in Mono.WebServer
mkdir: cannot create directory `2.0': File exists
GMCS  /out:2.0/Mono.WebServer2.dll
/usr/local/bin/mcs: line 2: /usr/local/bin/mono: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/mcs: line 2: exec: /usr/local/bin/mono: cannot execute: No such file or 
directory
make[2]: *** [2.0/Mono.WebServer2.dll] Error 126
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: The first thing to do is to fix your mono installation.

Comment: Got it working by make uninstalling everything, starting over and never using GTK+ within Monodevelop. Thank you for the advice

Comment: Would you like to write this up as an Answer for the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by make uninstalling everything, starting over and never using GTK+ within Monodevelop. Thank you for the advice